# Size of Dragons in Glorantha

Tags: glorantha

I'm currently reading the Guide to Glorantha and it sounds like True Dragons can extremely large.  A small one is described as 3 miles long.  It's also hinted that the Dragonspine mountains are literally that and according to the map the range is roughly 100 miles long.  Are there any printed sources for dragons and their size?  If so how big can they get and what books state that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no limits, because True Dragons are not creatures bound by the middle world. There are no printed guidelines even, because True Dragons aren't definable, in the same way (except not really the same way; see below) that the exact nature and even existence of the gods and Godtime are not definable.* True Dragons transcend physical reality, and the part of them that "bumps" into physical reality takes the shape, size, and nature it does for reasons that non-dragon minds cannot comprehend.

Basically, it's up to the GM and the "Your Gloranthat *Will* Vary" principle. Welcome to the frustration that is trying to learn Glorantha's canon!

On the plus side, there's lots of material that you can bounce off of to make sure your True Dragons are more-or-less within the spirit of Glorantha, and you've started gleaning some of that. As you keep on reading and unearthing mentions of dragons† you'll gather some general impressions, but also end up realising that Glorantha is *not* going to answer all your questions, on purpose, and it expects you to immerse into the metaphysics and start extrapolating your own answers and truths. Some bits on True Dragons:

- They're huge. Some mountain ranges are suspected or known to be True Dragons, or partially so. One very large valley is the result of a True Dragon getting up and moving elsewhere.
- They're somewhere between a physical creature and a manifested spirit, but they're also neither.
- True Dragons are mentally transcendant. It's unclear what that means practically or metaphysically, and they aren't telling. To understand, you have to be a True Dragon. (This is what dragonewt culture is all about achieving, apparently. Maybe. According to some human observers.)
- True Dragons, as far as they're concerned, predate Godtime and aren't constrained by *it* either. There appears to be evidence that they're right, too, but it's unclear. This hints that everything anyone knows about the metaphysical reality of Glorantha, from Godtime to the Underworld, is *wrong*. And it's going to cheekily refuse to confirm any of your suspicions about what that means. Have fun with that!
- There are lots of them.
- They sleep a lot and for a long time, and their dreams generate Dream Dragons, which are what most Gloranthans mistakenly believe to be actual true dragons, the poor benighted sods.
- Sometimes a True Dragon wakes up, and this disturbs the inconsequential mortals who might have been living near/on/downstream of the former landmass that was actually a True Dragon. (Or maybe just its physical projection. Regardless, the practical impact on the landscape and its inhabitants is the same)
- As a category, True Dragons are not interested in events that are critical life-and-death matters even to the Gods, but they do intervene sometimes anyway for reasons that are so inscrutable, they might just be coincidences. Or maybe they're not. And then, there are some rare exceptions who do make a policy of openly meddling in godly and even mortal affairs, and nobody knows why those few True Dragons do *that* either.
- Normal mortals can become True Dragons. Maybe? Or maybe those people in the EWF were liars and deceiving people. Or it was true, because they believed it was true and everything is true, but not *true*-true in the way that True Dragons are true transcendentally of even Godtime. (Maybe.) Assuming it is true, for some value of true, how it's possible was lost with the EWF, and no True Dragons nor dragonewts are volunteering to share. They're not volunteering to clear up whether it was even true in the first place, either.
- Dragonewts are vastly incomprehensible because their alien thinking and even existence is but the tiniest reflection of the vast incomprehensibility of True Dragons. (Never mind the World Dragon.)
- They're concentrated in Dragon Pass for some reason. There are hints that this has to do with Dragon Pass's metaphysical importance. Most Gloranthans who grasp this truth assume that it speaks to the Godtime (timeless) importance of Dragon Pass, but of course, the whole True Dragon thing hints that Godtime might be child's play and Dragon Pass is important at a wholly different level of metaphysics. Or maybe they just like Dragon Pass' climate.
- A True Dragon rules the vast Kraloreli Empire in the East. Maybe. They might just be a mortal claiming to be a dragon, which might itself be actually true, or not, as above with the whole EWF thing.

The meta-game conclusion I've personally come to is that True Dragons are Glorantha's way of saying that you can never fully understand Glorantha, *really truly no kidding*, even if you think you've finally grasped the whole everything-is-true-but-nothing-is-true thing. It's the next Inception layer that tells you everything is a lie, and then makes you question the very concept of true and false. And then maybe wonder what's beyond this layer that you can never fully see, because this layer refuses to be analysed and let you can peek behind its curtain.

Possibly, True Dragons are the lampshade that Glorantha, as seriously as it takes itself, is actually self-awarely a *game world*, and the existence of True Dragons serving to kinda-maybe but not clearly point to a a yet-higher meta-level of Glorantha's true reality is just Greg Stafford's way of pointing at the reader and entangling your own subjective aproach to Glorantha in the *canon* of its true underlying reality. This would fit in a cute, mischievous kind of way, with the "Your Glorantha *Will* Vary" mantra. Regardless, Greg is pointedly not saying.

True Dragons. Welcome to the rabbit hole.

<sup>* These things are not definable, except by choosing a culture's bias to see them through, but then you've already given up on truth an accepted a mere reflection of truth as good enough to work with. Note that the *Guide* is written from the Godlearner bias and nothing in the book should or *can* be accepted as "true", but rather is only one culture's attempt to render ineffable Truth into something that can be grasped by a middle world creature.</sup>

<sup>† They pop up in lots of unexpected places. No spoilers here, but read about course of the future Hero War in the *Guide*'s Appendix J for some very up-close material on the nature of True Dragons, or maybe just the nature of one. (Which is then contradicted by each different culture's first-person reports of what happened during that temple dedication ritual!)</sup>

Comment: Hadn't realized the Guide was from the God Learner's bias.  Either I missed that in the intro or more likely read it and missed the significance of it since I didn't know what God Learners were.  (I am entirely new to Glorantha.)

Comment: @mirv120 It's buried somewhere near the front, not prominent at all. It's almost not material, except as a *caveat lector*. It was chosen, far as I can tell, only because it's most compatible with an real-world writer's needs for tackling a setting book. The setting kind of "unfolds" as you keep reading things, so missing details appears to be expected and normal. It's definitely not something that can be absorbed fully in a single front-to-back reading.